# filter array from nested array in javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays, I need to filter this based on name.

```
const arr1 = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Car3", "Car2", "Van", "Bus"];
const arr2 = [
    {
        name: "Saab",
        url: "saab/"
    },
    {
        name: "Volvo",
        url: "volvo/",
        children:[
            {
                name: "Van",
                url: "van/"
            },
            {
                name: "Bus",
                url: "bus/"
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "BMW",
        url: "bmw/"
    },
    {
        name: "SUV",
        url: "suv/",
        children:[
            {
                name: "Car1",
                url: "car1/"
            },
            {
                name: "Car2",
                url: "car2/"
            },
            {
                name: "Car3",
                url: "car3/"
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried with this code.
`const result = arr2.filter((item) => arr1.includes(item.name);`

This code working fine but it does not check children object in `arr2`, I need to check based on the `arr1` values and if I have children object I need to check that name also. For example: name `SUV` is in the `arr1` but `car1` and `car2` value are not in `arr1` that time I need to remove that `SUV` object.

My output should be:

```
[
    {
        name: "Saab",
        url: "saab/"
    },
    {
        name: "Volvo",
        url: "volvo/",
        children:[
            {
                name: "Van",
                url: "van/"
            },
            {
                name: "Bus",
                url: "bus/"
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "BMW",
        url: "bmw/"
    },
]
```

How can I do this using `javascript`, is it possible to do in `es6`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another filter function to check `children` inside the filter function for that.

Explanation:

- checking `item` and `item.length` to be sure children exists and is not empty (you can remove the second one if not necessary, but it's safer because in most cases it assures that children is an array and that `.every` will not throw error)
- `.every` and `.includes` test if all children are in `arr1`
- for the second part of the alternative with `||` it is not executed if first part is true
- in this second part, you have to test `!item.children` because if first alternative fails on children, it would fallback on the result of `arr1.includes(item.name)` and "SUV" would come back in the result

```js
const arr1 = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "SUV", "Car3", "Van", "Bus"];
const arr2 = [
    {
        name: "Saab",
        url: "saab/"
    },
    {
        name: "Volvo",
        url: "volvo/",
        children:[
            {
                name: "Van",
                url: "van/"
            },
            {
                name: "Bus",
                url: "bus/"
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "BMW",
        url: "bmw/"
    },
    {
        name: "SUV",
        url: "suv/",
        children:[
            {
                name: "Car1",
                url: "car1/"
            },
            {
                name: "Car2",
                url: "car2/"
            },
            {
                name: "Car3",
                url: "car3/"
            },
        ]
    }
];

const result = arr2.filter( (item) => ( (item.children && item.children.length && item.children.every(v => arr1.includes(v.name))) || (!item.children && arr1.includes(item.name)) ) );

console.log(result);
```

**EDIT**: fixed code to meet requirements

**EDIT2**: turned into a pure ES6 answer, old fashioned not necessary now

Comment: thanks for posting I no need to return the "SUV" object itself

Comment: Yes give me the time to edit, I misunderstood your requirements (the explanation was a bit imprecise)

Comment: @techie18 edited the answer. I would usually use a regular `for` loop to optimize by exiting the loop if a children is not found though

Comment: Sounds a bit strange to set `i=l` to end the for loop. Instead, why don't you use `break`?

Comment: A personal habit I guess, never liked `break` keyword, if there is extra code in the second part of the `for` declaration, I'd prefer it to be executed

Comment: @Kaddath this filter is based on the children `name` value right? because if u have children filter should happen based on that only not "SUV" can pls check my   code I edited the question

Comment: @techie18 this was not mentioned in the question, on the contrary the part " check that name **also**" suggests both criterias should be met. I suggest you precise the question

Comment: @Kaddath sorry can pls check the `arr1` i removed the "SUV"

Comment: You should have chosen another one to remove, because "SUV" needed to @techie18 be removed anyway because one of the children is not in the array. So, just to be sure, if a parent name is not in the array but all children are, the item should be kept in result?

Comment: @Kaddath parent name ("SUV") will be optional when it has children. that time we need to check only with a children name only

Comment: I'll fix that tomorrow, gonna be busy

Answer (score 0):

you can use foreach on result and check the items value by last method (filter your nested array).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
res = arr2.filter(item2 => (arr1.findIndex(item1 => item2['name'] == item1) > -1))
```